# Java - Why is this pattern matching not working?

Tags: java, regex

```
public static String FILL_IN_THE_BLANK_REGEX = "\\\\[blank_.+\\\\]";

public static int getBlankCountForFillInTheBlank(String questionText) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(FILL_IN_THE_BLANK_REGEX).matcher(questionText);
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()) ++count;

    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(getBlankCountForFillInTheBlank("abc [blank_tag1] abc [blank_tag2]")); // prints 1
}
```

But if I do something like

```
public static String FILL_IN_THE_BLANK_REGEX = "\\\\[blank_tag.\\\\]";
```

It prints 2 which is correct.

'+' does not work here I don't know why.
(the blank tag can be anything like [blank_someusertag])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.+` will match ANY character 1 or more times.

Use the non-greedy `?` to ensure you only capture until the next defined expression.

Your working expression: `\\[blank_.+?\\]`

Answer (score 6):

See the [javadoc for `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). I believe it's because `+` is a [greedy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) quantifier and therefore matches everything it can. You can add a `?` after the `+` to make it reluctant.

```
public static String FILL_IN_THE_BLANK_REGEX = "\\[blank_.+?\\]";
```

will print

```
2
```

Comment: @XavierDSouza Don't worry about that. As long as you understand the problem and the solution.